# Problems reading in JP2 files in FME

Tags: fme-form, jpeg-2000

I'm trying to add JP2 files to fme and it gives me a very vague error when reading in the file. I have plenty of space and ram memory available for the process. I have also tried it on a more powerful computer and the result is the same. As I am a beginner with FME, I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong.
"JPEG2000 reader: `C:\Projects\Etosha e Okavango\Satelites\EO8-EO10_EO14_EO17.aux' exists but could not be opened. File contents may be invalid, or the file format may not be supported
Error running translation."

Comment: fyi for others, this was answered on the FME Community here: https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D5Dm00000GvYHiKAN/i-am-trying-to-clip-some-raster-images-but-im-having-trouble-reading-in-the-jp2-file-im-trying-to-use - the problem is of using 32-bit FME, when 64-bit is required. Based on that I suggest Close as "no longer can be reproduced"